# Does NPM automatically download all dependencies from your package.json when you distribute the project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, server, package.json

Does NPM automatically download all dependencies from your package.json when you distribute the project? I am asking because I created a project that I migrated from localhost to my web host and I needed to reinstall every single dependency before I could even run scripts from my package.json.

Comment: Anyone who pulls in your project will have to `npm install` to get all the required packages.

Comment: ok, thank you. I was just making sure.

Comment: The alternative to doing so would be to include all the node modules in your repository, which would be an unnecessary bloat to the repo size, given that they can all be retrieved upon demand from the centralized repo.

Comment: isn't "node_modules" the repository you refer to?

Comment: The repository (repo) he's referring to is your whole project folder :)

Comment: While we are going... you'll find a .gitignore file in the root of your repo, this is a plain text list of all of the things to 'ignore' and not share when you distribute your repo with git. Your .gitignore will contain the line  /node_modules